# Spring Kafka Non-Blocking how to get the retry attempt count

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

Having a Spring Boot Application with 2 listeners and no producers.
Kafka listeners are configured in order to support a Non-Blocking mechanism, using support from org.springframework.kafka.retrytopic classes.

Having this bean :

```
    @Bean
    RetryTopicConfiguration kafkaRetryTopicConfiguration(final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory,
                                                         final KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate) {

        return RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder
                .newInstance()
                .doNotAutoCreateRetryTopics()
                .autoStartDltHandler(false)
                .useSingleTopicForFixedDelays()
                .includeTopics(kafkaTopics.getConsumerTopics())
                .maxAttempts(maxAttempts)
                .fixedBackOff(backOffPeriod.toMillis())
                .retryTopicSuffix(
                        "-" + kafkaProperties.getConsumer().getGroupId() + kafkaProperties.getProperties().get("retry.suffix"))
                .dltSuffix("-" + kafkaProperties.getConsumer().getGroupId() + kafkaProperties.getProperties().get("error.suffix"))
                .listenerFactory(kafkaListenerContainerFactory)
                .create(kafkaTemplate);
    }
```

This configuration allows the retry mechanism to happen automatically, so I don't have to manually publish or consume any retry messages. Thus, I only have a single common @KafkaListener that consumes both main and retry messages.

What I am trying to achieve is being able to know the retry delivery attempt number inside the listener, so that I would be able to know whether a message is being retried for the first time or for the second time, based on the configurable maxAttempts (set to 3)

My end goal is to have a metric that shows how many messages were successfully consumed :

- on the main topic
- on the retry topic
- published on error dlt queue

Already managed to get the above done using interceptor. What I am still trying to achieve is to count messages processed:

- after the first retry attempt
- after the second retry attempt

Already tried multiple solutions, like other interceptors or implementing various kafka interfaces, such as ErrorHandlers, but couldn't achieve the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```java
@Header(name = RetryTopicHeaders.DEFAULT_HEADER_ATTEMPTS, required = false) Integer attempt
```

To your `@KafkaListener` method.

The header will be null the first time; after that it is held as an integer in a `byte[]` but the framework will perform the necessary convertion to an `Integer`.

```java
@Component
class Listener {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Listener.class);

    @KafkaListener(id = "app7", topics = "s1-app7")
    @RetryableTopic(attempts = "5", backoff = @Backoff(delay = 2000, multiplier = 1.5))
    void listen(String in, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
            @Header(name = RetryTopicHeaders.DEFAULT_HEADER_ATTEMPTS, required = false) Integer attempt) {

        log.info(in + " received from " + topic + ", attempt=" + (attempt == null ? 1 : attempt));
        if (in.equals("one")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("test");
        }
    }

    @DltHandler
    void dlt(String in, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
            @Header(RetryTopicHeaders.DEFAULT_HEADER_ATTEMPTS) Integer attempt) {

        log.info(in + " received from " + topic + ", attempt=" + attempt);
    }

}
```

```
2023-08-01 07:47:31,261 [app7-0-C-1] one received from s1-app7, attempt=1
2023-08-01 07:47:31,285 [app7-0-C-1] two received from s1-app7, attempt=1
2023-08-01 07:47:33,267 [app7-retry-2000-0-C-1] one received from s1-app7-retry-2000, attempt=2
2023-08-01 07:47:36,272 [app7-retry-3000-0-C-1] one received from s1-app7-retry-3000, attempt=3
2023-08-01 07:47:40,778 [app7-retry-4500-0-C-1] one received from s1-app7-retry-4500, attempt=4
2023-08-01 07:47:47,533 [app7-retry-6750-0-C-1] one received from s1-app7-retry-6750, attempt=5
2023-08-01 07:47:48,040 [app7-dlt-0-C-1] one received from s1-app7-dlt, attempt=6
```

Comment: Correction - you don't have to extract the attempt from the `byte[]`; just declare the parameter as an `Integer` and the framework will do the conversion for you - I edited the answer to show that.

Comment: Great answer. +1. Is there an example of the "right way to go" handling for kafka, like, dlq, retries, error handling, "redrive" messages after a fix, etc...